$\lim \sup$/ $\lim \inf$ inequalities fail when $\mu(X)=\infty$
I think this question was already answered in multiple places, e.g. here, but there is still one thing I cannot grasp:
Consider the measure $\mu$ and a sequence of sets $A_n$. Given the condition $\mu\left(\bigcup A_n\right) < \infty$, we have:
$$
\limsup \mu(A_n) \leq \mu\left(\limsup A_n\right)
$$
These inequalities fail whenever $\mu(X)=\infty$. I get where this is needed in the proof, but I cannot seem to remember it because I have no contradictory example in my head. So I would really appreciate an example of an infinite measure space X and a sequence of subsets where the inequality fails. Thanks a lot in advance.

Here's an easy example; consider the sets
$$
A_n=[n,\infty)
$$
Then,
$$
\lim\sup A_n=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty A_k=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty [k,\infty)=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty[n,\infty)=\emptyset \\
\implies\mu\left(\lim\sup A_n\right)=0
$$
However,
$$
\lim\sup\mu(A_n)=\lim\sup\infty=\infty
$$

fantastic, thanks a lot!
